# Delete a lot of words with one command

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a lot of links like

```
https://content.example.net/skin/frontend/2015/default/fonts/test.ttf
https://content.example.net/skin/frontend/2015/default/img/test.svg
https://content.example.net/skin/frontend/2015/default/fonts/test.eot
https://content.example.net/skin/forntend/2015/default/js/test.js
```

How can I delete links from a file that contain words in the url like
css, jpg, svg, png, ttf ..etc

Now use something like that

```
cat url.txt | sed '/png/d'  | sed '/jpg/d' | sed '/svg/d' | ...etc
```

This takes a lot of time and effort

Can this matter be replaced in one command?

Comment: Do the URLs occur alone on a line? Does the document contain any _other_ text that may contain the strings `png` etc. (e.g. ordinary English text, or other URLs that happen to contain those strings as substrings as in `http://example.com/png/mydir/thesis.txt`)?

Comment: I do not understand the question well, however
I will answer what I have understood
The file does not contain regular words
Rather, all lines are a url
example this 

`https://content.example.net/skin/frontend/2015/default/fonts/test.ttf
https://content.example.net/skin/frontend/2015/default/img/test.svg
https://content.example.net/skin/forntend/2015/default/js/test.js
https://content.example.net/skin/frontend/2015/default/fonts/test.ttf`

The only thing that could be a variable in the url
The name of the file folder that is in the file

Comment: While the accepted answer is the best solution considering usage of sed, you can also concatenate your sed pipe chain by using each pattern match with semicolon: `sed ‘/png/d; /jpg/d; /svg/d’ url.txt`.  While technically still several calls, which are worked on from left to right, it will not return to the command-line for another call of sed for each sub-command, but work on it internally.  And as stated in that answer, sed can handle files itself. So, no need to cat it for sed.

Comment: I forgot the dollar at the end of each pattern in my previous comment for end-of-line match only: `sed ‘/png$/d; /jpg$/d; /svg$/d’ url.txt`.  Otherwise, it matches the pattern anywhere in the line, not only the extension.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the "OR" syntax for regular expressions:

```
sed -E '/png|jpg|svg/d' url.txt
```

This will delete all lines containing either pattern. If you want to make sure that this pattern is the filename extension, i.e. that the pattern occurs *at the end of the line*, you can include an anchor into the regular expression:

```
sed -E '/(png|jpg|svg)$/d' url.txt
```

By the way, you never need to `cat` a file into `sed`; it can read them all on its own.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use Grep:

```
grep -vE '\.(svg|jpg|png)' file
```

`-v` only prints non-matching lines and `-E` enables extended regex.

`\.(svg|jpg|png)` is the regex, that matches `.svg` or .`jpg` or `.png`.

If you want to modify the file,

- Use Ed with the global command:

  ```
  printf '%s\n' 'g/\.\(svg\|jpg\|png\)/d' w q | ed -s file
  ```

  `g` is the global command, `d` deletes the matching lines, `w` saves the changes and `q` quits.
- In a GNU/Linux system with Bash and Vim,

  ```
  vim -e file<<<'g/\v\.(svg|jpg|png)/d|x'
  ```

  `g` is the global command again, `\v` disables the need to escape the parenthesis, and `x` saves the changes.

Answer (score 5):

`grep` is better suited.

Generate a pattern file, e.g.:

```
printf '\\.%s$\n' svg jpg png > patterns.txt
```

And remove lines with:

```
grep -vf patterns.txt url.txt
```

Or directly:

```
grep -ve "$(printf '\\.%s$\n' svg jpg png)" url.txt
```

Output:

```
https://content.example.net/skin/frontend/2015/default/fonts/test.ttf
https://content.example.net/skin/frontend/2015/default/fonts/test.eot
https://content.example.net/skin/forntend/2015/default/js/test.js
```

Answer (score 2):

**using Raku (née Perl 6)**

Taking the OP's original `url.txt` file and adding a dummy line ending with `*.txt`, here's an answer using Raku:

```
~$ cat url.txt | raku -ne '.say unless .ends-with( "ttf" | "svg" | "eot" | "js" );'
```

OUTPUT:

```
https://content.example.net/skin/forntend/2015/default/js/test.txt
```

The code above works for the specific case where you want to look at the ends of lines (it utilizes Raku's `ends-with` routine). Use `if` if you want to select for the presence of a line ending; use `unless` to select against the presence of a line ending (`unless` is equivalent to `if not`).

Note, the `ends-with` routine also takes an `:ignorecase` argument (abbreviated more simply as `:i`), should you have files named both `jpg` and `JPG`, etc.:

```
~$ cat url.txt | raku -ne '.say unless .ends-with( "ttf" | "svg" | "eot" | "js", :ignorecase );'
```

OUTPUT:

```
https://content.example.net/skin/forntend/2015/default/js/test.txt
```

HTH.

https://raku.org/